# SQL joins over more than two tables

Tags: sql

I have 4 tables:

- sales
- products
- vender_info
- venders

Question is: display list of product_id whose vender and customer is different.

Please solve this question.

[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SANS9.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried anything? This is not a coding service.

Comment: yes,
SELECT DISTINCT product_id
from vna_products
where (select customername from vna_sales where orderid in (select orderid from vna_products)) <>  (select vender_name from vna_vender_info where vender_id in (select vender_id from vna_products));

Comment: and i tried many other queries,but failed.

Comment: The task itself doesn't seem to make much sense. A product is sold by one vendor to *many* customers. So are you looking for products that a vendor never sold to themselves? Or for products they sold at least once not to themselves? (A strange idea anyway to sell something to oneself.) And you assume that when John Smith sold a product to some John Smith that this is the same person?

Comment: this is my college assignment question.....
i dont know question is wrong or right.

Comment: vender and customer different.....where is customer lies in this case...i mean which table

Comment: @Vinay: Yes but still one needs to understand it before solving it. And as is the task is abiguous to say the least. Maybe you made a mistake when translating it into English?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: customer lies in **sales** *table1* and vender's lies in **table 3**.

Comment: query apply on first three tables

Comment: And again: Are you supposed to find products that a vendor *never* sold to themselves or products that a vendor sold *not only* to themselves?

Comment: products that a vendor sold not only to themselves.

Comment: means,only names of customer and vender should not same of particular product

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look closely enough to your table image. So a product can only be sold *once* in *one* order to exactly *one* customer. This is an extremely strange data model, but then the question makes sense. The data model has another flaw by the way by storing the vendor names redundantly. It is a bad idea to teach SQL with a bad database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what would you do with this data, but this is the query:

```
SELECT vp.PRODUCT_ID, vv.VENDERS, vs.CUSTOMERNAME
FROM vna_sales vs
JOIN vna_products vp ON vs.ORDERID = vp.ORDERID
JOIN vna_venders vv ON vp.VENDER_ID = vv.VENDER_ID 
WHERE vv.VENDERS <> vs.CUSTOMERNAME
```

Comment: If you join to `vna_venders` then you should not join on `vender_id` alone, but also on `raw_material`. Or join to `vna_vender_info` instead (the name would then be `vender_name` instead of `venders`).

Comment: @zack , i trying following code to display total no. of orders by each vender every year: `select distinct vv.vender_name,vs.extract(year from orderdate) as year,vs.sum(orderquantity) as total_orders     from vna_sales vs     join vna_products vp ON vs.orderid=vp.orderid     join vna_vender_info vv ON vp.vender_id=vv.vender_id;` this gives ERROR:right paranthesis missing, where is mistake???

Comment: @Vinay This is a completely different issue with a new query. There are plenty of sql questions with "right parenthesis missing". Look them up, and see if any of them apply to you. It could be different things. And it can be something specific to the syntax of your db vendor. You never stated which one you are using (sql server, MySQL, oracle, ...). If you can't figure it out, post a new question, and provide all information. No screenshots, read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
SELECT * 
    FROM vna_shipments a
    inner join vna_parts b on a.id = b.id //some joing factor
    inner vna_suppliers c on a.id = c.id   //some joing factor
    inner vna_projects d on a.id = d.id  //some joing factor

    group by vendor_id, customer_id
    order by vendor_id desc
```

Comment: sorry,i updated tables photo....  there is no **parts,suppliers,projects and shipment** tables..
please check new photo..